# Pass Query String to Controller ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I would like to pass the productId through query string to the controller, which will retrieve data based on the productId. what is the proper way to pass the query string to the controller?

http://localhost:22343/Product?pid=1

```
Route("api/getdevice")]
    [HttpGet("{pid}")]
    public IActionResult GetById(string pid)
    {
        int PId = Convert.ToInt32(pid);

        var selectProducts = (from p in _db.product
                            where p.ProductId == PId
                            select p);
```

ProductId is the foreign key in the Device id and Device Id is the primary key.

AJAX:
url:api/getdevice

I'm trying to print the data to html.

Comment: C# can determine that 1 is an int, there is no need to use string in the signature. Regardless, this seems to be working, what is the problem with your code?

Comment: @TravisJ the problem that I'm having is 1 is not passing to the controller. When I debug the code it shows that pid is null.

Comment: The action name in the Route (getdevice), the Url (Product) and the Method (GetHotelById) are all different. Make them the same

Comment: Could you show us the code that call `GetById` action method?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're mixing api's. You're not supposed to use the RouteAttribute, but rather pass the full path to the HttpGet like this: `[HttpGet("api/getdevice/{pid}")]`

In order to pass the result you need to change the method signature to return whatever your product collection contains or project it to a dto if it contains a lot of stuff you want to hide from the consumers of the api, like this:

```
var process = _db.product.SingleOrDefault(p => p.ProductId == PId);
return process != null ? new MyDto(process) : null;
```

Comment: The reason I'm using the route attribute is that I'm trying to print the data to an HTML page. Sorry that I didn't include that earlier.

Answer (score 0):

In a common way, i use this, the parameter in the route.

```
[Route("api/getdevice/{pid}")] 
[HttpGet] 
public IActionResult GetHotelById(int PId) 
{ 
var selectProducts = (from p in _db.product where p.ProductId == PId select p);
 }
```

You can retrieve directly in the parameter the type, you don't parse.

And call this with:

```
http://localhost:22343/api/getdevice/1
```

Assuming with your base url is "/".

Regards,